# USB ports recieving power but not working on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: usb, power, power-supply, boot-issues, usb-power

I use external harddisk(connected via USB with its own power supply) to boot into dietpi on my raspberry pi. It works okay for a day(even with multiple reboots and poweroff). But the next day RPi sends no power to usb ports and so it doesn't boot.
 When I use SD card to boot it works. Ethernet port works and I'm able to SSH. I've plugged my external drive using the USB adapter to another computer and I can confirm that it is working. I am using the official power supply (2.5A 5.1V). 
If I try to boot after keeping the RPi off for more than 1 day from the external HDD it works again! But this repeats everytime.
I can't understand this peculiar behaviour of my rpi 3b.
I have also set **max_usb_current=1** in **boot/config.txt** but still no luck. 
***Here is the output of some of the commands I ran after booting with sd card on raspbian:***

**lsusb:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsblk:** *(with external HDD connected)*

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.6G  0 part /
```

**dmesg | grep usb** *(A lot of over-current change errors messages)*

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep usb
[ 1039.172044] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4012
[ 1039.430051] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4013
[ 1039.688057] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4014
[ 1039.946054] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4015
[ 1040.204102] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4016
[ 1040.461910] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4017
[ 1040.720016] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4018
```

**config.txt:**

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

program_usb_boot_mode=1

max_usb_current=1
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks :)

Update: I checked and found that there is 5V being supplied to USB ports(measured with multimeter between P1/P2 to P27) and I still don't know what's causing the problem. Even regular USB flash drive is not working. How can I diagnose the issue?

Comment: May be the external power supply is one part of the problem. Some rare devices ignore the USB spec and if connected to a power supply also send the power upstream to the USB host - in your case the Raspberry. I don't know what protections the Raspberry has on USB power level but if it has some resettable fuse the behavior you observed would be possible.

Comment: Okay so I measured voltage between PP3-PP27 as suggested here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=110164 and I found out for me it's fluctuating between 0.01V - 0.06V using the official power supply. I think that's too low? Maybe the power supply is faulty?